# Is there one word for higher "quality" and "volume"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am not sure if such a word exists, but I figured it good to ask anyway:

I'm looking for a single word to describe something that has both better quality, and also higher quantities or volume of something.

e.g.

> "Our oceans provide more quantity and better quality sustenance."
>
> "Our oceans provide better sustenance."

Is there a way to avoid other dull words like "better" or "more"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[abundant](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abundant)** ([overabundant](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/overabundant)) to describe something that exists in large amounts that are more than what's needed.

Near synonyms are **plentiful**, emphasizing "large amounts," and **ample**, emphasizing "more than enough

> "Our oceans provide sustenance **galore**."

**galore**

Galore means there’s so much that it’s unbelievable. 
The word is an example of a postpositive adjective, which means it comes after the word it describes.
([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abundant))

Comment: Thanks to all for such great answers! I do like *galore* and this what I ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

The term *[bountiful](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bountiful)* means

> Large in quantity; abundant:
>   *the ocean provided a bountiful supply of fresh food*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Similarly, *[abundant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/abundant)*

> (abundant in) Having plenty of something:
>   the riverbanks were abundant in wild plants

In both cases, the connotation is both volume and a positive quality.

Answer (score 2):

What's your intended flavor here? If you're going for flowery language, I would use *cornucopia*.

From [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cornucopia&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=define+cornucopia):

> Cornucopia: an abundant supply of good things of a specified kind.

So for your superlative case possibly something like, *"Our oceans provide a comparative cornucopia of sustenance."* or even a *"veritable cornucopia of"* for greater emphasis.

For a more clinical presentation, I would probably keep the adjectives separate. I think there's value in specifying that there is both more of and better quality of a thing. What I might do though, is link the adjectives together; something more like, *"Our oceans provide a greater amount of higher quality sustenance."*

Answer (score 1):

How about "**enhanced**"?

> "Our oceans provide *enhanced* quantity and quality sustenance."
>
> "Our oceans provide *enhanced* sustenance."

---

> **enhance** *verb*: intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of. "his refusal does nothing to *enhance* his reputation"
>
> **synonyms**: increase, add to, intensify, heighten, magnify, amplify, inflate, strengthen, build up, supplement, augment, boost, raise, lift, elevate, exalt
>
> [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=enhanced+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

*Great* can be used to refer to both high volume and high quality. Here are two of its definitions:

> 1. a :  notably large in size :  huge
>
>    b :  of a kind characterized by relative largeness —used in plant and animal names
>
>    c :  elaborate, ample: *great detail*
> 2. markedly superior in character or quality
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/great))

Thus, you could say ***Our oceans provide a greater quantity and quality of sustenance.***

Answer (score 0):

For certain applications, maybe *fecund*?

For others, perhaps *bounteous*?

Comment: Hi user and welcome to ELU! This is a great answer, but you should consider adding some definitions.